# Layer 2 Switches and IP address duplication

Tags: networking, routes, ip, switch-statement, cisco

Hello Networking Gurus,

I have a question about IP duplication and how this impact the associated switches (layer 2). Sorry, I don't have any resources available to test this. It would be great if someone can shed some lights of their experience on this.

If I have two servers (Linux), say `A` & `B`, serving exactly same contents and for some reason they both are assigned same IP address. To be more specific, if A already has an address `IP.100` and B has another address `IP.200`. Now at this point everything seems working and the switch has proper MAC addresses stored. If, later, `B` also gets the address `IP.100`, how would this affect the switch's `ARP` cache? When `B` gets the new address I assume it broadcasts ARP? to inform the associated switch.

So the question is, Does the switch stores both machines' entries? or overwrites the existing with new? Is there any standard behaviour or proprietary switches reacts differently?

If a client, with no ARP cache, tries to connect to IP.100, which machine would it be forwarded to? `A` or `B` or none? If `A` OR `B`, can I say from client point-of-view, that there's no outage? (Assume this is a static website, with no login sessions etc)

Feel free to point any relevant documentation.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Feel free to post this on a site where this would not be offtopic.

Comment: I'm not sure why would this be offtopic here?

Comment: This site is for programming questions. network theory isn't part of that

Answer (score 0):

In theory, you shouldn’t have two hosts talking on the same IP, unless they are participating in routing. Eg any-cast.  As things will break.

Each host will have its own MAC address.  If the switch is only doing layer two forwarding, then the switch only keeps track of MAC addresses. It is the end hosts or routers that track ARP entries.

If you move IP 100 to B, then the hosts will update their own ARP table.
But if A and B have 100 at the same time, this will cause issues.

Answer (score 0):

Switch will not see any IP's and do not have arp cache for forwarding packets , it will had only mac address table map macs to ports and macs in your case will be unique

Answer (score 0):

I actually think this is how multicast works.
Hosts obtain a multicast address and all of the devices share that same multicast address.
A switch will gather collections of Mac addresses to that same multicast in it's mac table.

I could be wrong though....Still learning.